# Function that takes a string representing a filename as an argument. Function returns number of letters in the txt file

Tags: python

I need to write a function that takes a string representing filename as argument, e.g. letter_count('alphabet.txt').
The function should open the file and return the number of letters (not digits or other characters) it contains.

Sorry for including doctest but I think it helps make it more obvious what is trying to be achieved.

```
def letter_count(filename):
    """
    >>> letter_count("anthem.txt")
    177
    >>> letter_count("digits.txt")
    0
    >>> letter_count("phrase.txt")
    10
    """

    myfile = filename
    count = 0
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    text = myfile.readlines()
    for char in text:
        if char in letters:
            count += 1
    return count


import string 
myfile = open(filename, 'r')
myfile.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
   import doctest
   doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Obviously I have made a mistake but I cannot pinpoint, any advice?

Comment: `myfile` doesn't exist in your function

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated it. There were a few issues with pasting. Greg, I have called the letter_count function in the doctest.

Comment: your `letter_count` still isn't being called...

Comment: I was of the understanding there is no need to call the function again in the main routine if its already being called in the doc test? I would just be repeating myself

Comment: pardon, I was not aware of the `doctest.testmod()` method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is only being opened outside your function.

Try this:

```
def letter_count(filename):
    count = 0
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            for char in line:
                if char in letters:
                    count += 1
    return count
```

Edit: Take a [closer look](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) at the [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement, it's quite handy here.

Comment: Came back saying 'filename' is not defined.

Comment: how did you invoke it?

Comment: Just left as is above, and put this code in place of the old function

Comment: That's most likely from your `myfile = open(filename, 'r')` block. What is the line number given in the traceback? Remove your lines `import string ... myfile.close()` and it'll work. What was your intent putting them there?

Comment: Thanks! Worked. The concept of the problem was simply lost on me so I was somehow thinking I had to incorporate a main routine.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add to your function the ability to open the `.txt` file within the function for instance the function bellow would accept a string and then open the file within the function:

```
def parseCSV(A):
    file = open(A,'r')
```